# Why don't the classes in the DBML designer appear in alphabetical order?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a DBML file with a very large data model. Whenever I need to add a relationship between to tables I have to select the other table from a combo box which appears to be in in almost random order. Is there a reason these dropdowns aren't in alphabetical order, or is there a way to put them in some kind of order?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the .cs code of your dbml file and put the classes in alphabetic order. However it is not safe as the code is autogenerated...